# Pass an object type as parameter

Tags: c#, object, types, parameter-passing

I would like to replace the following function, almost exact copies of this function exist in my project with only the object type that is different. What I would like to do is pass an object type as a parameter.

```
private void reloadBooks()
{
    var books = session.Query.All<Book>();
    boklist = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<Book>(books.ToList<Book>());

    lstBooks.ItemsSource = boklist;              
}
```

I was thinking about something like this:

```
private void getRecordsOfType(object objObject)
{
    System.ComponentModel.BindingList<objObject.GetType()> recordList = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<objObject.GetType()>();

    var records = session.Query.All<objObject.GetType()>();
    recordList = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<objObject.GetType()>(records.ToList<bjObject.GetType()>());

    return recordList;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, I get the following message:

> "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'"

I read something similar about using generics but I don't see that being useful in this situation.

Comment: Well you *are* trying to use generics - you're trying to pass `objObject.GetType()` as a generic type argument. But type arguments are evaluated at compile-time, not execution time. You should make *your* method generic too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics is exactly what you want:

```
private BindingList<T> getRecordsOfType<T>()
{
    var records = session.Query.All<T>();
    return new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>(records.ToList<T>());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
private System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> getRecordsOfType<T>()
{
    System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> recordList = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>();

    var records = session.Query.All<T>();
    recordList = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>(records.ToList<T>());

    return recordList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a generic type parameter:

```
private BindingList<T> getRecordsOfType<T>()
{
    var records = session.Query.All<T>();
    recordList = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>(records.ToList<T>());    
    return recordList;
}
```